# How to change text field text using if/else if string is NULL or 0?

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, nsstring, uitextfield

Below is my code:

```
if(PREREQUISITEstring == (NSString *)[NSNull null] || [PREREQUISITEstring isEqual: @"0"]) {
  PREREQUISITEfield.text = @"2";
} else { 
  PREREQUISITEfield.text = PREREQUISITEstring;
}
```

I am 100% sure that `PREREQUISITEstring` is "0" and it shows as "0" when I'm debugging but when it comes to runtime, that string doesn't change to 2, it stays as 0.

edit: I got the code to work by using this instead

```
if(PREREQUISITEstring == (NSString *)[NSNull null] || [PREREQUISITEstring isEqual: @"0"]) {
  PREREQUISITEstring = @"2";
} else { 
  PREREQUISITEfield.text = PREREQUISITEstring;
}
```

in the if statement, i changed PREREQUISITEfield.text -> PREREQUISITEstring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(PREREQUISITEstring == (NSString *)[NSNull null] || [PREREQUISITEstring isEqual: @"0"]) {
PREREQUISITEstring = @"2";
} else { 
PREREQUISITEfield.text = PREREQUISITEstring;
}
```

this is the code i used, replace

`PREREQUISITEfield.text`

with

```
PREREQUISITEstring
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop in the debugger at the start of the if statement and check both conditions in the debugger.  Obviously, both are false, but there's not enough context provided to tell you why.

Also, are you sure you mean to compare to `[NSnull null]` and not `nil`?